# How can one change a Windows 2000 computer name in .NET 2.0?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-2.0, hostname, computer-name

I'm trying to change a computer's name (host name) on Windows 2000 using .NET 2.0.  The computer is not joined to a domain.

Windows XP and higher provides the WMI method `Win32_ComputerSystem.Rename`, but this is not available in Windows 2000 ([reference here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa393056(VS.85).aspx)).

I'm not averse to just calling an external program if I need to, but I also can't seem to find one that works on Windows 2000. Searching on Google didn't seem to turn up anything obvious.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the Windows API might be of help on Windows 2000: Use [**`SetComputerNameEx`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724931%28VS.85%29.aspx):

```
BOOL WINAPI SetComputerNameEx(
  __in  COMPUTER_NAME_FORMAT NameType,
  __in  LPCTSTR lpBuffer
);
```

This sample is based on the sample on [pinvoke.net](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/kernel32/SetComputerNameEx.html):

```
public class RenameComputer
{
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    static extern bool SetComputerNameEx(COMPUTER_NAME_FORMAT NameType, string lpBuffer);

    enum COMPUTER_NAME_FORMAT
    {
        ComputerNameNetBIOS,
        ComputerNameDnsHostname,
        ComputerNameDnsDomain,
        ComputerNameDnsFullyQualified,
        ComputerNamePhysicalNetBIOS,
        ComputerNamePhysicalDnsHostname,
        ComputerNamePhysicalDnsDomain,
        ComputerNamePhysicalDnsFullyQualified,
    }

    //ComputerNamePhysicalDnsHostname used to rename the computer name and netbios name before domain join
    public static bool Rename(string name)
    {
        bool result = SetComputerNameEx(COMPUTER_NAME_FORMAT.ComputerNamePhysicalDnsHostname, name);
        if (!result)
            throw new Win32Exception();

        return result;
    }
}
```

In addition to p-invoking the WinAPI you might also use `Process.Start` in combination with the `netsh` command as described [here](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=259313).

Comment: A-ha, I'm sure this will work, I'll accept this as soon as I can try it out.

Answer (score 0):

There is an example in C under that link. You could pinvoke that